# Compare Two Arrays based on key value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a Quiz engine and am comparing answers.

I have two arrays

correct answers :

```
 0 => "a"
 1 => "a"
 2 => "a"
 3 => "c"
```

Chosen Answers...

```
 0 => "c"
 1 => "b"
 2 => "a"
 3 => "b"
```

So based on this, I know (from comparing myself) that I have 1 correct answer.

Is there a PHP function that can compare the keys and the values and increment a number of similar?

I've looked at array_intersect and array_difference but they don't seem to give me the desired answer.

Thanks

Comment: Use array_diff_key()  for example plz refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Comment: *"Is there a PHP function that can compare the keys and the values..."* -- that's the only purpose in life for [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php). *"... and increment a number of similar?"* -- it returns an array that contains the common pairs, all you have to do is to use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to, ahem, count them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short solution using [***array_intersect_uassoc***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-uassoc.php) function (on extended input arrays):

```
$correct = ["a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "c"];
$chosen =  ["c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"];

$result = array_intersect_uassoc($correct, $chosen, 'strnatcmp');
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => a
    [4] => a
)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, Just out of curiosity, What does the strcmp do?

Comment: @StuBlackett, welcome, `strnatcmp` here is **key** comparison function to check for keys equality along with values

Comment: @StuBlackett, Though, if your input array would have more than 9 items, use `strnatcmp` function (to properly compare `1` and `10`)

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that would generate an array for each key and if the answer was correct (1, or 0 if wrong) that way you can not only quickly calculate the score but use the array to display the questionnaire result later. Like showing which questions were right and which ones were wrong.

```
<?php
    $corrects = array(
         0 => "a", 
         1 => "a", 
         2 => "a", 
         3 => "c"
     );

    $answers = array(
        0 => "a", 
        1 => "a", 
        2 => "a", 
        3 => "c"
    );

    function verify($answers, $corrects) {
        $results = array();

        foreach($corrects as $question => $correct) {
            $results[$question] = $correct == $answers[$question] ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return $results;
    }

    $results = verify($answers, $corrects); 
    $score = array_sum($results);
?>
```

It leaves room for more complex scoring or multi correct answer question etc.

Comment: Love this! Thank you Giles! I do need to review the answers, So this will help further